# How to check if NPM cache already contains a tarball

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-cache

I am looking at the cache docs:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

if I ran this:

```
npm cache add lodash@x.y.z
```

how can I check later, if this is in the npm cache?

I don't see `npm cache get lodash@x.y.z` in the docs...

Comment: this is what I currently have to check if the npm cache has a certain package, but I don't think it's correct. https://github.com/ORESoftware/npm.cache/blob/master/src/cache-has.ts

Comment: this will be help . try with cacache module that  managing local key and content address cache. https://github.com/zkat/cacache

Comment: @channasmcs update that library to TypeScript and I might use it

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `npm` has not a direct way to achieve this, but this script does the trick

create a file `cache.js` and paste code below

```
const cacache = require('cacache/en')
const cachePath = require('os').homedir()+'/.npm/_cacache'

cacache.ls(cachePath)
  .then((packages) => {
    for(const i in packages) {
      console.log(packages[i].key)
    }
  })
```

run

```
npm install cacache
```

then run

```
node cache.js | grep lodash
```

personal opinion: `yarn` is designed to cache npm packages, if you are going to do that, you could give it a chance

EDIT: I made a script that does all of the above, every feedback is welcome

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-cache

Comment: Any idea why it's called `_cacache`?

Comment: @AlexanderMills usually the initial _ indicates "private"

Comment: I was more curious about the 'ca' part not the _ part

Comment: @AlexanderMills - the **ca** part is most likely:  _**c**ontent **a**ddress cache_.